# How to display image in wide color gamut under ios and android Oreo via openGL?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

Ios and android Oreo support wide color gamut (color management). Via openGL how to make that my app can render bitmaps with embedded wide color profiles loaded from PNG, JPEG ? I m under Delphi

I read from the android doc that we can use wide color gamut mode in OpenGL doing somethink like this (for example) :

```
std::vector<EGLint> attributes;
attributes.push_back(EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_KHR);
attributes.push_back(EGL_GL_COLORSPACE_DISPLAY_P3_EXT);
attributes.push_back(EGL_NONE);
engine->surface_ = eglCreateWindowSurface(
    engine->display_, config, engine->app->window, attributes.data());
```

but in this way how can I on the same form (so the same surface as delphi use one surface to render a form), how can I render one texture with sRGB and also another one with embedded wide color profile because not all my bitmaps have embedded wide color profiles ?

Comment: As I recall from Bitmaps, the embedded profiles are applied automatically when loaded from an existing image resource when they are available.  Did you find the solution that were looking for?  Did you first load from an image resource and then make a decision point for your color space attribute at run time?